# SQL Server stored procedure: finding the values of Odd and even

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm using `@subno` as Input. And I had to find the odd and even numbers. 16 is not a fix and it can be any other number. My question is how to find the odd and even number of my input?

Lastly, subno includes ( . ) dot at any position. e.g 123456.789123 I need to find the odd and even number of "123456" and the odd and even number of "789123" the dot ( . ) is the separator.

Once you find the odd for the left side, sum them up together. Once you find the even number for left side sum it up as well and then add the total odd to the total even values. That goes the same for the right side eg "789123".

Please help me. this is my 2nd week of trying to find the solution. Once you find all the total values for each side, multiply them together. example "123456" - total value of odd and even * the "789123" total value of odd and even.

It is for the the check digit validation. Validating the subscriber number. after validating through the calculation it should match the calculated reference number to the valid check digit number. It's the business rule. Kind of algorithm

```
create procedure ProcedureName
    (@subno VARCHAR(16),   --Input the 16 subscriber number
     @result INT OUT,
    )
as
begin
    IF(LEN(@subno) <> 16)
        SET @result = 1 -- INVALID RESULT
    ELSE
       IF(@subno % 2 = 0)
           SET @result = @subno - even numbers
       ELSE
           SET @result = @subno --odd numbers
end
```

Please see below my sample work

```
-- this is the sample

create procedure   ProcedureName
(
@subno VARCHAR(20),   --Subscriber no
@result INT OUT,      --result is invalid for 1, valid for 0
@payamt int
)
as

DECLARE @WA VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @Weights varchar(9)
DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @WD INT
DECLARE @WP INT
DECLARE @A INT
DECLARE @B INT
DECLARE @R INT
DECLARE @WR INT

SET @WR = 0
SET @R = 0
SET @A = 0
SET @B = 0
SET @WP = 0
SET @I = 0

BEGIN

IF (LEN(@subNo) = 7) AND (SUBSTRING(@subno,1,1) = '2') OR (SUBSTRING(@subno,1,1) = '9')
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 0 --VALID
    END
ELSE IF(LEN(@subno) = 8) AND (SUBSTRING(@subno,1,1) = '2') OR 
(SUBSTRING(@subno,1,1) = '9')
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 0 --VALID
    END
ELSE IF(LEN(@subno) = 9)
BEGIN
    SET @WA = SUBSTRING(@subno,1,2)
        IF(@WA = '65')
            set @result = 1 -- INVALID
        else
        BEGIN
        SET @Weights = '12121212'
        SET @WA = SUBSTRING(@subno,9,1)
        SET @WD = 0
        SET @I = 1
        WHILE @I<9
        BEGIN
            SET @WP = cast(SUBSTRING(@Weights, @I,1)as int) * cast(SUBSTRING(@subno, @I, 1) as int)
            IF(@WP > 9)
            BEGIN
                SET @A = SUBSTRING(CAST(@WP AS VARCHAR),1,1)
                SET @B = SUBSTRING(CAST(@WP AS VARCHAR),2,1)
                SET @WP = CAST(@A AS INT) + CAST(@B AS INT)
            END

            SET @WD = @WP + @WD
            SET @I = @I + 1
        END

        SET @R = @WD % 10

        IF(@R <> 0)
            SET @WR = 10 - @R
        ELSE
            SET @WR = @R

        IF(@WR <> CAST(@WA AS INT))
        BEGIN
            SET @result = 1 -- INVALID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @result = 0 -- VALID
        END
    END
END
ELSE IF (LEN(@subno) = 10)
BEGIN
    SET @I =1
    SET @WD = 0
    SET @Weights = '121212121'
    SET @WA = SUBSTRING(@subno,10,1)
    WHILE(@I < 10)
    BEGIN
        SET @WP = CAST(SUBSTRING(@Weights, @I, 1)AS INT) * CAST(SUBSTRING(@subno, @I, 1) AS INT)
        IF(@WP > 9)
        BEGIN
            SET @A = SUBSTRING(CAST(@WP AS VARCHAR),1,1)
            SET @B = SUBSTRING(CAST(@WP AS VARCHAR),2,1)
            SET @WP = CAST(@A AS INT) + CAST(@B AS INT)
        END

        SET @WD = @WP + @WD
        SET @I = @I + 1
    END

    SET @R = @WD % 10

    IF(@R <> 0)
        SET @WR = 10 - @R
    ELSE
        SET @WR = @R

    IF (@WR<> @WA)
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 1 -- INVALID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 0 -- VALID
    END
END
ELSE
    SET @result = 1 -- INVALID
END
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you would call the procedure and expected output.

Comment: Hi Sir, done editing.

Comment: This simply makes no sense:  'I need to find the odd and even number of "123456" and the odd and even number of "789123" .'

Comment: It is for the the check digit validation. Validating the subscriber number. after validating through the calculation it should match the calculated reference number to the valid check digit number. It's the business rule. Kind of algorithm

Comment: What is your expected output? The phrasing of your question makes it unclear what you want.

Comment: @ZLK My expected output should be the calculated Odd and Even for left side before the ( .) dot operator sum with the total odd and Even for right side. After getting the total number for each side, multiply them together.

Comment: "Once you find the odd for the left side, sum them up together. Once you find the even number for left side sum it up as well and then add the total odd to the total even values." - That statement is equivalent to saying add all the digits together. What significance is odd and even in this question?

Comment: count (the total number of odds) + count (the  total number of even )? and not digits just the count?

Comment: @FakeisMe counting or adding there is no relevance to odd and even. count (the total number of odds) + count (the total number of even ) is exactly the same as count(the total number of digits).

Comment: @Sean Pearce : U are right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the values which u get . Then iterate iver each side and add them. Please see the sample below.

```
declare @v varchar (16) , @num1 varchar(20) , @num2 varchar(20)
set @v = '1234567.78906656'

select  @num1 = substring(@v,0,charindex('.',@v))

select @num2 = substring(@v,charindex('.',@v)+1,len(@v))
--select @num1 = convert(int, substring(@v,0,charindex('.',@v)))
--select @num2 =  substring(@v,charindex('.',@v)+1,len(@v))
declare @index int = 1 ,@len INT , @char CHAR
declare @TotalOddL int  = 0
declare @TotalEvenL int  = 0
DECLARE @FullTotL INT = 0
declare @TotalOddR int  = 0
declare @TotalEvenR int  = 0
DECLARE @FullTotR INT = 0
DECLARE @TEMP INT
set @len= LEN(@num1)



WHILE @index <= @len
BEGIN
set @char = SUBSTRING(@num1, @index, 1)
SET @TEMP = cast(@char as int)
IF(@TEMP % 2 = 0)
   SET  @TotalEvenL = @TotalEvenL + @char
     else
   SET  @TotalOddL = @TotalOddL + @char

   SET @FullTotL = @TotalEvenL + @TotalOddL 


SET @index= @index+ 1
END

Select 'LeftSide total' , @FullTotL
Select 'Left Side odd' , @TotalOddL
Select 'Left Side Even' , @TotalEvenL

SET @index = 1
set @len= LEN(@num2)
WHILE @index <= @len
BEGIN
set @char = SUBSTRING(@num2, @index, 1)
SET @TEMP = cast(@char as int)
IF(@TEMP % 2 = 0)
   SET  @TotalEvenR= @TotalEvenR + @char
     else
   SET  @TotalOddR = @TotalOddR + @char

   SET @FullTotR = @TotalEvenR + @TotalOddR 

SET @index= @index+ 1
END


select 'TotalRSide' , @FullTotR
select 'RsideOdd' , @TotalOddR
select 'RSideEven' , @TotalEvenR

select 'Multiplied value' , @FullTotR * @FullTotL
```

Comment: This code does the same, i.e. there is no relevance to odd and even: declare @v varchar(16) = '1234567.78906656';

Select 'LeftSide total', len(substring(@v,0,charindex('.',@v)))
select 'TotalRSide', len(substring(@v,charindex('.',@v)+1,len(@v)))
select 'Multiplied value' , len(substring(@v,0,charindex('.',@v))) * len(substring(@v,charindex('.',@v)+1,len(@v)))

Comment: @FakeisMe I am still trying to work it with my code right now. Will get back to you as soon as I am done. Thank you.

Comment: it didnt work. it only calculated how many odd and even digits not the value of an input.

Comment: value of which input ? sp input or each character ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure prc_even_odd(i_number in number, o_result out varchar2)
as
begin
    if (mod(i_number,2) = 0) then
        o_result := 'EVEN';
    else
        o_result := 'ODD';
end prc_even;
```